# Confusion related to a context sensitive grammar

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I want to know if I have the following rule

AB -> BA.

Is it context sensitive?

Another rule 
A -> aAB

Is it context sensitive as well.

I think both of them are not context sensitive. Any insights or guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both grammars are context free. But context free grammars are subset of  the context sensitive grammars. ([Grammar hierarchy](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Chomsky-hierarchy.svg/200px-Chomsky-hierarchy.svg.png) ) So yes they are context sensitive grammars.

Comment: can you explain why they are context sensitive?

Comment: the rule for context sensitive is aAb -> aYb, where a and b may be empty, Y is a string of terminals and nonterminals, so AB -> BA satisfies this rule, A and B - nonterminals, A -> aAB, in this case you may assume aAB as the Y in the rule (aAb -> aYb and a,b empty). I hope this helps

Comment: just to add you a link, here is easy to understand: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar)

Comment: how come AB->BA is context sensitive I still don't get it. What do you mean by A and B -non terminals, what are a,A,b and Y in that case.

Comment: sorry it was my fault. actually AB-> BA is not context sensitive, but  A -> aAB is context sensitive. non terminal symbol as A, B means that it may go to non terminal or terminal symbol. terminal means that cannot go to other symbos it is end state. Y in this rule is a list of terminals and non terminals. So you have the base rule aAb -> aYb, as an example: Xi -> HXi (and HXi -> HHXi), in this case X is non terminal like A in the rule, HX is the resulting Y word. So  A -> aAB satisfies the rule aAb -> aYb (a,b are empty and A -> Y, where Y = aAb, the grammer may be A -> aAb -> aaAbb->aaaAbbb)

Comment: You cannot find such a,b, A, Y to correspond to AB -> BA for your case